# How to do RAML sync between Anypoint Studio and Design Center

Tags: mule, raml

I am using Mule 4 and Anypoint Studio 7 . I have imported code from design center and generated the flows. Now how to do a API (Raml) sync between Design Center and Anypoint Studio .If i add new resource/method pairing it is not reflected. Earlier there used to be API sync option in studio.

Answer (score 0):

API Sync is not currently available for Studio 7 and organizations migrated to the November 2017 release.